# Javascript GPA calculator printing issue

Tags: javascript, html

My code(shown below) doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure out why. When I open the webpage in my browser, I am able to take in user inputs for the credits(1,2,3,4,5) and the scores(A,B,C,D,F)  but I am unable to display the calculated GPA under the input table. Is there an error in the calculation or in my printing? I have looked up similar questions but the method and issues seem to be different from mine. I'm fairly new at this I would really appreciate some help on where I'm going wrong.

EDIT: Made a few changes as per comments, but it still doesn't work

The code is as follows:

```
<html>

    <head>
    <meta charset= "utf-8">
    <title > GPA Calculator </title>

   <script type="text/javascript">

    function gpa(){
        var A,B,C,D,F;
        var score = [A,B,C,D,F];
        var credit = [4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0];
        var inputCredit = [document.calcForm.credit1.value, document.calcForm.credit2.value, document.calcForm.credit3.value,
                            document.calcForm.credit4.value, document.calcForm.credit5.value];
        var inputScore = [document.calcForm.score1.value, document.calcForm.score2.value, document.calcForm.score3.value,
                            document.calcForm.score4.value, document.calcForm.score5.value];

        var sumcr = 0;
        var sumsc = 0;
        var validity =0;
        for(var j=0; j<5; j++){
            for(var i=0; i<5;i++){
                if(inputScore[i] == score[j]){
                    sumsc += credit[j] * inputCredit[i];
                    sumcr += inputCredit[j];
                }
            }
        }

        var gpa2 = sumsc/sumcr;
        return gpa2;
    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    .....

        <script type="text/javascript">GPA: document.write(gpa());</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First place to start is opening browser dev tools console (F12) and check errors thrown. Those are big clues. Read and understand the messages and how they tell you where exactly in the code the error gets thrown. Many messages are easily researched by pasting in search engine also

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the tip! I tried that and I have 2 errors; ReferenceError: A is not defined (which I can't make sense of after I looked it up) and character encoding not declared (which was easily fixed)

Comment: Well ...there is no variable `A` defined in the code shown (or the other letter variables). You can't magically use a variable that hasn't been previously declared

Comment: @charlietfl, the A is referring to line 10, var score = [A,B,C,D,F]; it is used to declare the array, score. Do A, B ,C,... need to be declared on their own for example; var A, Var B,..?

Comment: Yes.... would be a good starting poing to do some research on how javascript variables and variable scopes work. Should be easy to find lots of tutorials. The error is telling you exactly what is wrong (with part of the code anyway). Once you fix that there will be other issues to track down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> var A,B,C,D,E;
> ```

declares those variables with default value, which is `undefined`

> ```
> var score = [A,B,C,D,F];
> ```

collects those values (not the variables, and certainly not their names) in an array. Then the `if` tries to compare those `undefined`-s to something.

What you actually need is an array of the text markings A,B...

```
var score = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
```

(and the `var A,B,C,D,E;` line is not needed at all)

The `<script>` tag at the end is both broken and unnecessary. The `gpa()` function could display the result instead of returning it (`onclick=...` does not do anything with returned results anyway). You can try `document.write(gpa2);`, though it will replace everything. Or just add a `<div id="result"></div>` somewhere (like below the form), and then `gpa()` could end with `result.innerText=gpa2;`.

From the top of my head I do not remember if the `document.calcForm.something`-s really work, but if you add `id`-s (like in the suggested `result`), they work for sure.

---

For your follow-up question: style is changed via changing, `style`:

```js
function doThing(){
  var idx=["A","C","D"].indexOf(grade.value.toUpperCase());
  if(idx===-1){
    result.innerText="Invalid grade. Only A, C and D are permitted.";
    result.style="background:red;color:white";
  } else {
    result.innerText="Numerical value: "+[1,3,4][idx];
    result.style="background:green;color:yellow";
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" id="grade">
  <button type="button" onclick="doThing()">Clicky</button>
</form>
<div id="result">Result comes here</div>
```

Comment: thank you! I went with the `<div id="result"></div>` method. How do you set a default value, for example, 0 for gpa2 so it prints out 0 even if the calculate button is not pressed and there are no inputs? Also is it possible to change the text color of the gpa number with this method?

Comment: @n350 added a simplified snippet with styling from code, plus also showing `indexOf()` (which can replace the for loop) and `toUpperCase()` (which can allow users to enter either a or A). But honestly, you should get books/tutorials about HTML5, JavaScript, and perhaps a bit of CSS. This collection may be a good start, also for other languages: https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md - as far as I see it links to legal sources

Answer (score 0):

var score[5] = {A,B,C,D,f};
this is invalid syntax, in javascript you cannot fix the size of the array with the variable name. You can try doing this

```
var score = [A,B,C,D,F]
```

also replace the curly brackets with the square ones.

Comment: Thanks! I changed my arrays but unfortunately, I am still not receiving any output
`  var score = [A,B,C,D,F];
  var credit = [4.0,3.0,2.0,1.0,0.0];
  var inputCredit = [document.calcForm.credit1.value, document.calcForm.credit2.value, document.calcForm.credit3.value,
       document.calcForm.credit4.value, document.calcForm.credit5.value];
  var inputScore = [document.calcForm.score1.value, document.calcForm.score2.value, document.calcForm.score3.value,
       document.calcForm.score4.value, document.calcForm.score5.value]; `

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to just give you the answer, but I think if I give you this, you can kind of see the differences between how you were trying to do it and a working example. It may even shed light on some aspects of JS that you weren't aware of. I'll leave the styling up to you, for the most part :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
      <title> GPA Calculator </title>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function gpa(e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          const scores = document.getElementsByName("score")

          const credits = []
          scores.forEach(score => credits.push(Number(score.value)))

          const d = document.getElementById("result")
          d.innerText = "GPA: " + credits.reduce((acc, x) => {
            return acc + x
          })/scores.length;
        }
      </script>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor = "#CCEEFF" > 
        <h1 align ="center">GPA Calculator</h1>
        <form name ="calcForm" align="center">
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 10px">
          <label for="score" style="width: 50px">Calculus 2</label>
          <select name="score">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            <option value="4.0">A</option>
            <option value="3.0">B</option>
            <option value="2.0">C</option>
            <option value="1.0">D</option>
            <option value="0.0">F</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 10px">
          <label for="score" style="width: 50px">Physics 2</label>
          <select name="score">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            <option value="4.0">A</option>
            <option value="3.0">B</option>
            <option value="2.0">C</option>
            <option value="1.0">D</option>
            <option value="0.0">F</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 10px">
          <label for="score">History 3</label>
          <select name="score">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            <option value="4.0">A</option>
            <option value="3.0">B</option>
            <option value="2.0">C</option>
            <option value="1.0">D</option>
            <option value="0.0">F</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 10px">
          <label for="score">Chemistry 2</label>
          <select name="score">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            <option value="4.0">A</option>
            <option value="3.0">B</option>
            <option value="2.0">C</option>
            <option value="1.0">D</option>
            <option value="0.0">F</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; padding-bottom: 10px">
          <label for="score">Biology 3</label>
          <select name="score">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            <option value="4.0">A</option>
            <option value="3.0">B</option>
            <option value="2.0">C</option>
            <option value="1.0">D</option>
            <option value="0.0">F</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <button type="click" onclick ="gpa(event)">Calculate GPA</button>
      </form>
      <div id="result" align="center" style="margin-top: 5px">GPA: </div>
    </body>
</html>
```